# SonarLint : Code Smell : Local variables should not be declared and then immediately returned or thrown

Tags: reactjs, sonarqube, sonarlint

After analyzing my code with SonarLint, I get the following smell code: "**Local variables should not be declared and then immediately returned or thrown**".

Even if this is not blocking and the component works perfectly.

I think there is a better way to post the **return** in the function but I don't see how, if anyone knows the trick.

here is my component :

```
const ColumnModalEvent = (currency: any) => {
  const columnsEventModal: Column[] = [
{
  Header: () => <I18nWrapper translateKey="movement.type.fieldName" />,
  accessor: 'type',
  disableSortBy: true,
  Cell: ({ value }) => (
    <I18nWrapper translateKey={value} prefix="movement.type" />
  ),
},
{
  Header: () => (
    <I18nWrapper translateKey="movement.uniqueReference.fieldNameShort" />
  ),
  accessor: 'uniqueRef',
},
{
  Header: () => <I18nWrapper translateKey="movement.documentDate" />,
  accessor: 'createdDate',
  className: 'text-end',
  headerClassName: 'text-end',
  Cell: ({ value }) => <DateFormater dateToFomat={value} />,
},
];

 return columnsEventModal;
 };

 export default ColumnModalEvent;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just for code brief, change the first line from

```
const columnsEventModal=  Column[] = [...]
return columnsEventModal;
```

to the line

```
return [...]
```

because you dont do anything in between insertion and return statement, Sonar doesnt understand why you would allocate a variable

Comment: to add to this, in order to keep your type checking, I would also add a return type to the function - `const ColumnModalEvent = (currency: any): Column[] => {...` and/or use `as` on the return, i.e. `return [...] as Column[];`

Comment: I believe you are right and  I would do too but I don't know react, I just love Sonar